# Restangular errors when added to a project: `Error: $injector:modulerr`

Tags: javascript, angularjs, restangular

When adding Restangular to a project it throws sn `[Error: $injector:modulerr]` error. I've ensured this error isn't being thrown by one of my own modules. I've followed the docs on setting it up and I'm pulling from their CDN. If Restangular is removed as a dependency it works.

Reproduced below:

js:

```
angular.module('app', ['restangular'])
.controller('Main', function(){
    this.msg = 'Hello World'
})
```

html:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/restangular/1.3.1/restangular.js"></script>

<main ng-app="app" ng-controller="Main as vm">
  <h1>{{vm.msg}}</h1>
</main>
```

Reproduced in a [codepen](http://codepen.io/agconti/pen/rVQrdg?editors=101).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So you're missing an _.js dependency. I was able to update your CodePen, and made your code

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.4.4/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/restangular/1.3.1/restangular.js"></script>
<main ng-app="app" ng-controller="Main as vm">
    <h1>{{vm.msg}}</h1>
</main>
```

just to prove no magic here's a plunker
http://plnkr.co/edit/OvUefl8x0H6dvZs2B0ls?p=preview

Comment: very interesting. Its strange they don't mention this in their docs. ( if they do please point it out to me. I'm not sure how I could have missed it. )

Comment: Ahh found [it](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#dependencies). They should update they're add this your project instructions.

Comment: Their live demo has this reference as well - http://plnkr.co/edit/d6yDka?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

Restangular depends on Angular and Lodash (or Underscore).

[Look this](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#dependencies)